# Why do I never need to use the Secure Boot Password? (No MOK Management Screen)

Tags: ubuntu, secure-boot, zorin

Recently I've been trying out Ubuntu and Zorin OS and in both cases I was asked to create a secure boot password during the installation that you would be promted to enter when starting up the system for the first time. From what I can tell you would normally be greeted with a blue MOK Management Screen before logging in, but it never appeared for me despite having secure boot enabled. Same thing happened when I installed newer drivers on Zorin - I was asked to create a password, but never prompted to use it.

So does anyone have any ideas of why this could be happening? The reason I'm asking is because I'm worried that secure boot isn't properly working, or that I've messed up my UEFI somehow.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

---

For reference I'm running on a Z97-A motherboard.

I've disabled CSM and am running in UEFI-mode.

I've recently been enabling and disabling secure boot a lot while distrohopping.

Last time I re-enabled it I was running Fedora 38, and updated the signature keys to the latest ones through its graphical interface.

Secure Boot successfully blocked Pop! OS.

A couple of years back I tried updating my BIOS and wasn't successful on the first try.